# How can I find out what my last message was in Skype 5.3.0.111's news and alerts

Tags: skype

Earlier I used this feature to give some status information. Later I was forced to open Skype Home. No I do not like the standard view. But now even there I see only an empty input box, an empty list of messages and some advertisement.

Can I find out, what my last message was with out using Virtual machines and second accounts and the like?